# Where can I order thumbsticks for my PS3 dualshock 3 controller?

Tags: ps3, controllers

My son has a nervous habit of chewing on the PS3 controller's thumbsticks during cut-scenes.  One day, he actually ripped the top of it off.  Glue worked for awhile, but the top eventually came off again.  **Where can I find/order new thumbsticks for my controller?**  It seems a shame and a waste to drop $40+ on a new controller.

**Update:** The thumbsticks are model number NXPR3R-004, and work with both PS2 and PS3.  Armed with this, [a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nxp3r-004) turns up a lot of options.

Comment: Sorry I laughed quite a lot reading your question! How old is your son? It could clearly happen here with my daughter as well. One solution (but I don't know why I won't post it as an answer) is to bypass cut-scenes... ;)

Comment: You should see what the kid does to his shirts…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [Google Shopping search](http://www.google.com/search?q=DualShock+3+Analog+Stick+repair&tbs=shop:1) turns up a few results for me.

If you need directions, iFixit.com has some for [Installing DualShock 3 Analog Stick Covers](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-DualShock-3-Analog-Stick-Covers/3256/1) among [other DualShock 3 directions](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/DualShock_3).

Comment: Sweet.  [Here is the page for all PS3 parts sold by vpgames.com](http://www.vpgames.com/c-162-repair-parts.aspx).

Comment: The new thumb sticks came today and the controller has been repaired.  If I could give you double points, I would.

Comment: We'll help you with that. ;-) @splatteredbits