# Neighbor controlling my PS3 or random buttons triggered?

Tags: ps3, controllers

I have a Playstation 3 which I use for gaming and streaming video.  Often times, my PS3 is controlled by a mysterious force, which I can only assume is my neighbor.  I live in the city in a row house, so our neighbor's living room is likely just one (very thick) wall away.

Is there anything I can do to prevent my PS3 from being controlled by my neighbor's controllers?

Comment: They shouldn't be able to do so, unless they're synced to your PS3.  Does he come by (or do you go there) with your controllers?

Comment: The neighbor has never visited or attempted to use those controllers on my PS3. I have not visited them.

Comment: Then it won't be your neighbor doing this.  How many controllers do you have?  Are they all accounted for?

Comment: I have 2 controllers, both are accounted for.  Could it be a malfuction with my controller?

Comment: What does this "mysterious force" do with your PS3?

Comment: Could be.  How is it being controlled?  Can you describe what happens?

Comment: I'll be watching a movie and the netflix menus will navigate on their own, leaving the show I'm watching and moving the selection left and right  and selecting things with the controllers while simply sitting on the table unattended.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have another TV and/or a remote or something connected to the PS3, would you?  If they're navigating out of your show, and selecting something specific, that sounds like someone else trying to use the PS3.

Comment: Only one TV in the house in use at the time. No other controllers used with that PS3 in the house besides those two.  No other devices ever used with the PS3. It does sound like someone else trying to use the PS3 from my end, I can only guess at my neighbors using a ps3 as well to accidentally control it.

Comment: PS3 controllers use bluetooth to sync up to the correct device.  It literally should not be possible for a controller not synced to your PS3 to control your PS3.  Any chance you might be able to go talk to him and see if something similar happens to him?

Comment: Are they 3rd party controllers? I've occasionally had issues with off-brand controllers behaving badly (especially once they start to get old)... otherwise the "dirty" answer is probably correct.

Comment: Well it's obviously ghosts, who you gonna call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem with my PS3, the problem turned out to be dirty controllers.

The effect was much more noticeable when I wasn't playing a game as the controllers were not in constant use but symptoms were very similar, random inputs causing the menus to pop up and navigate the menus, usually in one direction constantly.

The simplest solution was to turn the controllers off once you have started watching the show then turn them back on again once its done. I would try this first then you can maybe look into cleaning your controllers with [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49259/easy-way-to-clean-a-dualshock-3) or buying a new one if it turns out to be the cause.

Other simple things to do in order to narrow down the problem is check to see if it happens when you are using a specific one of your controllers by recording which of the two is in use when it happens.

Comment: Thought of this last night as well. I've turned off the controller I was using when experiencing the issue and will use the other controller for a week and see if this happens again.  If I don't have any issues, I'll take the 'bad' controller apart and see what might be causing this (or just buy a cheap replacement).

Comment: Any luck diagnosing the problem?

Comment: So far it appears that the mysterious force is my second controller triggering random button presses. We havn't had issues while using the other controller withy the 'bad' controller powered off.