# Why is my input device changing rapidly?

Tags: pc, controllers, mortal-kombat-x, assassins-creed-rogue

Whenever I am in the options menu trying to adjust my options (I haven't gone in-game yet), my input device changes rapidly from my keyboard/mouse to my controller and the cursor goes up/left randomly (making it hard to adjust my options). I have pulled out the battery pack on my controller, nothing changes, same goes for my wireless adapter when I unplug it. A different wireless 360 changed nothing too. Restarting also didn't do anything. The issue also happens with Mortal Kombat X,What should I do?

Comment: Did you try removing the controller itself? The USB of wireless thingy I mean.

Comment: @ardaozkal My controller is wireless. I have an adapter for my PC that allows me to use it wirelessly.

Comment: I mean that you should try taking the wireless adapter too.

Comment: @ardaozkal I did. I said that, " I have pulled out the battery pack on my controller, nothing changes, same goes for my wireless adapter."

Comment: Sometimes just the fact that system sees it can cause problems with games, hence I asked you to remove it by hardware, not just the wireless adapters and the controllers batteries.

Comment: Saw your edit. Thanks for clarifying. [Very weird problem indeed.](https://xkcd.com/1316/)

Comment: @ardaozkal No problem

Comment: Possible dupe of this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/194073/neighbor-controlling-my-ps3-or-random-buttons-triggered

Comment: @Colin It's not my neighbors controllers and it only happens with Rogue.

Comment: Probe question:  When the controls change, do they keep resetting to KB/M or to the controller? (The game might be using a timestamp to determine which one is active, so finding out which one becomes "default" means we should look around there for the answer.)

Comment: Did you launch the game through Steam? I had an issue where Big Picture mode messed up with the input settings of one of my games, faking a XInput controller and constantly going up. I had to restart Steam (and launch via the normal UI) to fix this.

Comment: @NBN-Alex They rapidly switch from the KB/M to the controller back and forward without me pressing anything on any input device/

Comment: @SmileyBarry I launched through Steam but not Big Picture mode.

Comment: Do you have a gaming keyboard? They sometimes have fake input devices to allow macros to work. My Logitech one has fake controller & mouse devices installed. If you do, try unplugging it and just using the mouse/controller.

Comment: @SmileyBarry Yeah I do, a Logitech G105. I try launching from uPlay but Steam still opens it up with Rogue.

Comment: Then try this: close the Logitech Gaming Framework app, uninstall (**don't** delete the drivers) the emulated devices ("Device Manager" > "View" > "Devices by connection" >  anything under "Logitech Gaming Virtual Bus Enumerator") and unplug the keyboard. Then try to relaunch the game and see if it still happens. If you're worried about the uninstall phase, you can skip it and first try to just exit & unplug.

Comment: @SmileyBarry The issue still occurs when unplugged.

Comment: Did you try to exit the Logitech Gaming Software app? And uninstall the devices?

Comment: @SmileyBarry Not yet.

Comment: @SmileyBarry I finally finished Fallout 4 and tried it, but I got nothing. I'll refund the game if nothing else works soon.

Comment: Not the keyboard or mouse, I replaced both but to no avail.

Comment: have you tried to enter safe mode and attempt to uninstall the driver that way?

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I haven't tried safe mode. I have defragmented my hard drive but still nothing. I am looking to buy it for the Xbox 360 at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It apparently was my SNES USB controller. A (probable) Chinese company by iBuffalo produced it and was messing around with my keybindings. I have no idea if it inflicted any spyware on my machine, but pulling it out solved the problem. Arma 3 told me that the SNES USB controller was trying to set binds or being pressed. If someone similarly has this issue, try to unplug USB devices.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the commented solutions worked, your computer might be the problem.

Your hard drive could be corrupted, your operating system could be out of date, your USB port could be failing to register that there is something in it because it could be dirty or malfunctional, you may have to consider getting a wired controller, you may (at the very least) need a new wireless adapter, or the problem could possibly be with the gaming keyboard.

Basically, if none of these works, you'll need a new computer or something along those lines.

Comment: It is not my hard drive, as everything else works, my copy of Windows 10 is up-to-date, my USB ports work, my wireless adapter is in pristine condition, and my gaming keyboard is working fine. I refunded the game and planning to get it for the Xbox 360.

Comment: I tested out on MKX and getting the same issue. I'll try a different keyboard.

Comment: Not the keyboard or mouse.

Comment: Then I honestly have no idea how to help. I apologize for any inconvenience or "false hope" I may have caused.